# How can I make the child of my Drawer a Column?

Tags: flutter

I created a Drawer with a child of a ListView like the core documentation suggests.  It works.  But I want to put a widget fixed at the bottom of my drawer.  So I wrapped my ListView in a Column.  But when I do this my Drawer contents disappear completely.

```
final Widget _leftDrawer = Drawer(
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: <Widget>[
          DrawerHeader(
            child: Image.asset('assets/images/logo_1024.png'),
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: Text('Line 1'),
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: Text('Line 2'),
          ),
          AboutListTile(),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you put a ListView inside a Column, the ListView does not know about its boundary anymore. You need to wrap your ListView inside an [Expanded](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) widget.

```
    final Widget _leftDrawer = Drawer(
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: ListView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            children: <Widget>[
              DrawerHeader(
                child: Image.asset('assets/images/logo_1024.png'),
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: Text('Line 1'),
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: Text('Line 2'),
              ),
              AboutListTile(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
```